# Почему функция Python не возвращает ожидаемое представление колонки Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, генераторы, yield

Рассчитываю функцию поиска корня в уравнении `dichotomy()` способом дихотомии и затем вывожу значения с помощью декоратора `print_dichotomy()`. Полагаю, что в итоге увижу колонки **корень - значение функции в корне - погрешность - сходимость**. Однако на деле получаю так, что из столбцов ожидаемо выводятся лишь *корень* и *значение функции*, а две другие колонки некорректны. В них *погрешность* представлена лишь одним значением (остальные строки `NaN`), а *сходимость* - все ее значения оказались в одной строке.

Я не стал расписывать суть функции `dichotomy()`, поместив в нее списки псевдозначений для колонок Pandas.

В чем ошибка?

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):
        *res, func, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))
        func = list(map(lambda x: f'{f(x):.10f}', res))
        result_table = pd.DataFrame()
        result_table['Корни'] = pd.Series(res)
        result_table['Значения функции'] = pd.Series(func)
        result_table['Погрешность расчета'] = pd.Series(eps_list)
        result_table['Сходимость'] = pd.Series(prev_roots)
        print(result_table)
    return wrapper

def f(x):
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4 * np.cos(2 * x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):

    # 1. создаем переменную-список для хранения значений корня
    prev_roots = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
    # 2. создадим список для хранения погрешностей расчета
    eps_list = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
    # 3. создадим список для хранения корней
    roots = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
    for i in roots:
        root = i 
        # 4. возвращаем корень
        if root:
            yield root
      
    # 5. возвращаем значение погрешности расчета корня, сходимости 
    yield eps_list, prev_roots

dichotomy(0.0001, 50, 0.000001, 0.000001)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в некорректных передаче и приёме данных между функциями.

1. Из `dichotomy()` вы возвращали `yield eps_list, prev_roots`, что эквивалентно `yield (eps_list, prev_roots)`, т.е. кортежу из двух списков. Эти списки вы потом и увидели в виде значений во фрейме. И, поскольку эти списки не "распаковались" в ячейки фрейма, то остальные значения стали NaN.
2. Во `wrapper()` в выражении `*res, func, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))` вы принимаете значения, возвращаемые функцией - генератором `dichotomy()`, в переменные. Начиная с конца:

- в `prev_roots` передается вышеупомянутый кортеж `(eps_list, prev_roots)` и заполняет 2 первые строки колонки "Сходимость" (ниже данных нет, поэтому NaN);
- в `eps_list`заходит последнее (шестое) значение из списка `roots` - 0.03, оно же и становится значением первой строки столбца `Погрешность расчета`;
- в `func` заходит предпоследнее (пятое) значение из списка `roots` - 0.03, но далее нигде не используется (пропадает);
- оставшиеся 4 первых значения из списка `roots` передаются в переменную `res` и отображаются в четырех строках столбца `Корни`.

Таким образом, результатом является фрейм, состоящий из 4, а не из 6, как ожидалось, строк, и данные в нем расположены неправильно.

Не углубляясь в причины выбранного подхода и не устраняя избыточность кода (например, преобразования `list()`, `pd.Series()`), минимально скорректировал код, чтобы выдавалось (надеюсь) желаемое:

```
def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):
        *res, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))
        func = list(map(lambda x: f'{f(x):.10f}', res))
        result_table = pd.DataFrame()
        result_table['Корни'] = pd.Series(res)
        result_table['Значения функции'] = pd.Series(func)
        result_table['Погрешность расчета'] = pd.Series(eps_list)
        result_table['Сходимость'] = pd.Series(prev_roots)
        print(result_table)

    return wrapper


def f(x):
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4 * np.cos(2 * x)


@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):
    # 1. создаем переменную-список для хранения значений корня
    prev_roots = [0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016]
    # 2. создадим список для хранения погрешностей расчета
    eps_list = [0.021, 0.022, 0.023, 0.024, 0.025, 0.026]
    # 3. создадим список для хранения корней
    roots = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
    for i in roots:
        root = i
        # 4. возвращаем корень
        if root:
            yield i

    # 5. возвращаем значение погрешности расчета корня, сходимости
    yield eps_list
    yield prev_roots



dichotomy(0.0001, 50, 0.000001, 0.000001)
```

Вывод:

```
   Корни Значения функции  Погрешность расчета  Сходимость
0   0.03     0.7137557376                0.021       0.011
1   0.03     0.7137557376                0.022       0.012
2   0.03     0.7137557376                0.023       0.013
3   0.03     0.7137557376                0.024       0.014
4   0.03     0.7137557376                0.025       0.015
5   0.03     0.7137557376                0.026       0.016
```

Что поменял:

- из `*res, func, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))` убрал  `func`, чтобы не отъедалась последняя строка результата;
- `yield eps_list, prev_roots` разбил на 2 строки, иначе возвращался кортеж в одну переменную, а надо два списка в две;
- разнообразил тестовые значения `prev_roots` и `eps_list` для наглядности.

Answer (score 1):

````
import pandas as pd

def print_dichotomy(funcs):
    def wrapper(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):
        *res, func, eps_list, prev_roots = list(funcs(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg))
        func = list(map(lambda x: f'{func(x):.10f}', res))  # Исправлено f(x) на func(x)
        result_table = pd.DataFrame()
        result_table['Корни'] = pd.Series(res)
        result_table['Значения функции'] = pd.Series(func)
        result_table['Погрешность расчета'] = pd.Series(eps_list)
        result_table['Сходимость'] = pd.Series(prev_roots)
        print(result_table)
    return wrapper

def f(x):
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4 * np.cos(2 * x)

@print_dichotomy
def dichotomy(a, b, eps_func, eps_arg):

    # 1. создаем переменную-список для хранения значений корня
    prev_roots = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
    # 2. создадим список для хранения погрешностей расчета
    eps_list = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
    # 3. создадим список для хранения корней
    roots = [0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
    for i in roots:
        root = i 
        # 4. возвращаем корень
        if root:
            yield root
      
    # 5. возвращаем значение погрешности расчета корня, сходимости 
    yield eps_list, prev_roots

dichotomy(0.0001, 50, 0.000001, 0.000001)```
````

Comment: в итоге получаю ошибку `'float' object is not callable`. У меня сложилось впечатление, что `res` как раз отрабатывает нормально, а проблемы возникают в двух следующих колонках